Decomposition of $(x \pm i y) \, Y_{l m}$ and $z \, Y_{l m}$ on spherical harmonics
Using the various algebraic properties of the associated Legendre polynomials $P_l^m(u)$ and of the spherical harmonics $Y_{l m}(\theta, \varphi)$, I was able to decompose the following expressions, but the algebra involved was really non-obvious and tedious:
$$\tag{1}
\cos \theta \: Y_{lm} \equiv \frac{z}{r} \: Y_{lm} = a_{l + \smash{\frac{1}{2}},\, m} \, Y_{l + 1,\, m} + a_{l - \smash{\frac{1}{2}},\, m} \, Y_{l - 1,\, m},
$$
(notice the $l \pm \tfrac{1}{2}$ indexes on the coefficients), where
$$\tag{2}
a_{l m} = \sqrt{\frac{(l + \frac{1}{2})^2 - m^2}{4 l (l + 1)}},
$$
and
$$\tag{3}
\sin \theta \, e^{i \varphi} \, Y_{l m} \equiv \frac{x + i y}{r} \, Y_{l m} = b_{l m} \, Y_{l + 1,\, m + 1} - c_{l m} \, Y_{l - 1,\, m + 1},
$$
where
\begin{align}
b_{l m} &= \sqrt{\frac{(l + m + 1)(l + m + 2)}{(2l + 1)(2l + 3)}}, \tag{4} \\[1ex]
c_{l m} &= \sqrt{\frac{(l - m)(l - m - 1)}{(2l + 1)(2l - 1)}}. \tag{5}
\end{align}
I also got something similar for $\sin \theta \, e^{- i \varphi} \, Y_{l m}$, with a different sign in front of $m$ in (4) and (5), and a different global sign for (3).
While I already have a complete algebraic solution to get (1) and (3), I'm not satisfied with the horrible manipulations I had to do, to get $a_{l m}$, $b_{l m}$ and $c_{l m}$.  So I'm wondering if there's a better way in getting the results, without using explicitly the Legendre polynomials algebraic properties and differential equations.  Is there an "operator way" (or another way?) to get the coefficients of (1) and (3)?
The goal of this decomposition is to evaluate the following integrals (this is easy once we know (1) and (3), since the spherical harmonics are orthogonal and normalized):
\begin{align}
\oint \frac{z}{r} \: Y_{jk}^{*} \: Y_{lm} \, d\Omega, \tag{6} \\[1ex]
\oint \frac{(x \pm i y)}{r} \: Y_{jk}^{*} \: Y_{lm} \, d\Omega. \tag{7}
\end{align}

What do you mean by an "operator" approach, as oppose to an algebraic (Racah algebra?) approach? afaik, when dealing with operator expressions, you use algebraic expressions, e.g., the contraction rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Contraction_rule

@JEB, by operator based approach, I mean something similar to what we do with creation/destruction operators, or with $L_{\pm}$ and $L_z$ for the angular momentum.  I guess that what I'm looking for doesn't exist.  We could consider $z$ and $x \pm i y$ as operators acting on $| l, m \rangle$ for example.

well $z$ and $x\pm iy$ are $Y_{l=1}^{m=(-1,0,1)}$ so the product with $Y_l^m$ is the same as adding the angular momentum of a spin 1 particle to an already existing orbit angular momentum state, and you can start with the extremal case: $|j=l+1, j_z=l\rangle = |l, l\rangle|1, 1\rangle$ and then apply $J_- = L_ -+ S_-$ and see what you get. (Also: in angular momentum, they're called "ladder" operators, and are nilpotent, you eventually get $0$, while in the SHO the creation operator is unbound, while some power of  the annihilation operator gives $0$).

The [Wigner-Eckart] theorem was invented to solve exactly this type of problem. Especially in this case where it is difficult to find the results for some quantum number values, while for others it is easy. The theorem shows how they are all related by Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.
Of course you then need those CG coefficients. When I was a student those where among the most important pages of the
[Particle Data Group Pocket Book]. Today of course you find it online:[Particle Data Group]
(EDITED:) Let's explicitly use the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients to compute Eqs. (6) and (7) of the question. From the [relation to spherical harmonics] and reality of the CG's, we see that:
$$
  \int\! d \Omega\,\ Y_{\ell_1 m_1} Y_{\ell_2 m_2} Y^*_{\!_{\large L M}}
  = \sqrt{\frac{(2 \ell_1 + 1) (2 \ell_2 + 1)}{4 \pi (2 L + 1)}}
   \ \langle \ell_1 \, 0 \, \ell_2 \, 0 | L \, 0 \rangle
   \ \langle \ell_1 \, m_1 \, \ell_2 \, m_2 | L \, M \rangle
$$
and we can then use:
$$
 \frac{z}{r} =\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3}}\ Y_{10} \quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{x\pm iy}{r} =\mp \sqrt{\frac{8\pi}{3}}\ Y_{1,\pm 1} 
$$
Since CG coefficients are well known functions, we just look up the ones we need:
\begin{align}
\langle 1 \, 0 \, \ell \, m |\ell\!+\!1, \, m \rangle &=
\sqrt{\frac{(\ell+1)^2-m^2}{(\ell+1)(2\ell+1)}}  \tag{1.1}
\\[6pt]
\langle 1 \, 0 \, \ell \, m |\ell\!-\!1, \, m \rangle &=
-\sqrt{\frac{\ell^2-m^2}{\ell(2\ell+1)}}  \tag{1.2}
\\[6pt]
\langle 1,  \pm 1,\, \ell \, m |\ell\!+\!1, \, m\!\pm\!1 \rangle &=
\sqrt{\frac{(\ell+1\pm m)(\ell+2\pm m)}{2(\ell+1)(2\ell+1)}}   \tag{1.3}
\\[6pt]
\langle 1,  \pm 1,\, \ell \, m |\ell\!-\!1, \, m\!\pm\!1 \rangle &=
\sqrt{\frac{(\ell-1\mp m)(\ell \mp m)}{2(\ell+1)(2\ell+1)}}  \tag{1.4}
\end{align}
There was a time when, to find these expressions, we would have looked for instance in [Abramowitz & Stegun], but nowadays it is easier to use Mathematica. For example, $(1.1)$ is found with:
In[3]:= FullSimplify[ ClebschGordan[{1,0},{l,m},{l+1,m}],
    Assumptions->{m>=-l,m<=l,l>=0, Element[{l,m},Integers]} ]

             (1 + l - m) (1 + l + m)
Out[3]= Sqrt[-----------------------]
                (1 + l) (1 + 2 l)

Clearly, the above contains all ingredients to get the closed-form expressions we want. To avoid mistakes, combining the factors also can best be checked with the symbolic solver, leading to: (note the subtle differences with Eqs. $1.1\ \dots\ 1.4$)
\begin{align}
  \int\! d \Omega\,\ \frac z r \ Y_{\ell m}\, Y^*_{\ell+1,m}
  &= \sqrt{\frac{(\ell + 1)^2-m^2}{ (2 \ell + 1)(2\ell+3)}}
\\[6pt]
  \int\! d \Omega\,\ \frac z r \ Y_{\ell m}\, Y^*_{\ell-1,m}
  &= \sqrt{\frac{\ell^2-m^2}{4 \ell^2 - 1}}
\\[6pt]
  \int\! d \Omega\,\ \frac {x\pm iy} r \ Y_{\ell m}\, Y^*_{\ell+1,m\pm 1}
  &= \mp \sqrt{\frac{(\ell+1\pm m)(\ell+2\pm m)}{(2\ell+1)(2\ell+3)}}
\\[6pt]
  \int\! d \Omega\,\ \frac {x\pm iy} r \ Y_{\ell m}\, Y^*_{\ell-1,m\pm 1}
  &= \pm \sqrt{\frac{(\ell-1\mp m)(\ell\mp m)}{4\ell^2-1}}
\end{align}
Obviously this also immediately gives us the coefficients for Eqs. $(1)$ and $(3)$ of the question.

The problem with this, there's isn't a general formula as a function of $l$ and $m$, for the case I'm interested in (AFAIK).

Your stated goal was to evaluate (7) and (8), you can do that by just using the CG coefficients (they are well-known functions, admissible in a general expression) together with the reduced matrix element which in this case does have a closed-form expression. And even if you also want (1) and (3), they are in fact the defining relation for the CG's:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Formal_definition_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients
(Maybe I should edit the answer to clarify this some more...)

Actually, like I said in my query, I already have the coefficients.  But my method of calculations is very heavy, messy and not very "pretty" (I used most of the Legendre polynomials relations and diff equations).  I'm interested in another proof, more elegant if any, so using directly the CG coefficients without an explicit proof is useless to me.

The question as it is, nevertheless deserves an answer where the "standard approach" of using the CG's is used. (It might be of interest for other readers, so I now added most of the details in my answer.)
